# True/False type Questions with xsim package

Tags: xsim

How to make true/false type questions in 'xsim' package? In the manual of 'xsim', I could not find it.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[verbose,clear-aux]{xsim}
\usepackage{xsimverb,listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem,amssymb,fmtcount}



\xsimsetup{
    exercise/print = true,
    solution/print = true,
    path=./exercises,
    file-extension = tex,
    exercise/template = bonus,
    grading-table/template = default*
    }

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{xsim package }

\begin{document}
    \begin{exercise}
         A first true-false example for an exercise(T/F).
         \end{exercise}
     \begin{solution}
         A first example for a solution(T).
         \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe you could use something like the multiple choice question shown in example 13 of the xsim manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So basically a true/false question is a multiple choice question with binary choices. Therefore I came to the same conclusion as [leandriis in his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134144/leandriis) and started with example 13 of the manual (`xsim.multiplechoice.tex` in your TeX distribution).

[image: xsim example]

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: 1}
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[verbose,clear-aux]{xsim}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{tf}
  {%
    \UseExerciseTemplate{begin}{default}%
  }
  {%
    \IfInsideSolutionF{%
      \par\vskip\baselineskip\noindent
      Select whether this is true or false: $\Box$ true\quad $\Box$ false}%
    \UseExerciseTemplate{end}{default}%
  }

\DeclareExerciseType{tf}{
  exercise-env = truefalse ,
  solution-env = booleansolution ,
  exercise-name = Question ,
  solution-name = Solution ,
  exercise-template = tf ,
  solution-template = tf ,
  counter = exercise
}

\xsimsetup{
  truefalse/print = true,
  booleansolution/print = true,
  path=./exercises,
  file-extension = tex,
  exercise/template = bonus,
  grading-table/template = default*
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{truefalse}
        A first true-false example for an exercise(T/F).
    \end{truefalse}
    \begin{booleansolution}
        A first example for a solution(T).
    \end{booleansolution}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is giving error:
Undefined control sequence. \begin{truefalse}

Comment: @cosmicraga Did you copy my code as is? The `\begin{truefalse}` is defined in the exercise type. It compiles fine here (TL2019/pretest on Linux).

Comment: Yes. I had to delete all the previously existing .aux and other files from the folder. Then it worked correctly. Thank you.

Comment: It will be great if the format is like following:

Comment: The question should look like : The earth is the fourth planet from the sun. True. False.

The answer should look like : The earth is the fourth planet from the sun. True. False. (False in bold)

Comment: May I modify the actual question with this last requirement?

Comment: @cosmicraga It would be better to ask a new question with that exact requirement.

Comment: Posted as new question